# Fill blank cells with data above it

Tags: python, pandas

I have data which looks like:

```
| ID       | Name      | Inv | Date       | Value | PO  | Type  | Rate  | Tax   | Integ |
|----------|-----------|-----|------------|-------|-----|-------|-------|-------|-------|
| DEADBEEF | CHEMICALS | 321 | 19-11-2017 | 14288 | UK  | State | 0.00% | 3000  | 0     |
|          |           |     |            | 0     | 0   | 0     | 5.00% | 10750 | 537.5 |
```

The software which generated this left banks for repeated data. The blank cells seen here should have the data seen in the cell above it.

The above data must ideally be like:

```
| ID       | Name      | Inv | Date       | Value | PO  | Type  | Rate  | Tax   | Integ |
|----------|-----------|-----|------------|-------|-----|-------|-------|-------|-------|
| DEADBEEF | CHEMICALS | 321 | 19-11-2017 | 14288 | UK  | State | 0.00% | 3000  | 0     |
| DEADBEEF | CHEMICALS | 321 | 19-11-2017 | 14288 | UK  | State | 5.00% | 10750 | 537.5 |
```

As you can see the columns 1-7 have been populated with the data seen above it. How do I do this in `pandas`.

**I need to:**

- Identify `blanks` or `NULL`s in "ID" (column 1)
- Populate that row: column 1 ot 7 with the data above that row.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) with forward filling missing values:

```
df = df.mask(df == 0).ffill()
```

Or:

```
df = df.mask(df.isin(['', 0])).ffill()
```

If want also change first row filled by missing values to `0` only for numeric columns:

```
num = df.select_dtypes(np.number).columns
d = dict.fromkeys(num, 0)
print (d)
{'Inv': 0, 'Value': 0, 'Tax': 0, 'Integ': 0}

df = df.mask(df == 0).ffill().fillna(d)
print (df)
         ID       Name    Inv        Date    Value  PO   Type   Rate    Tax  \
0  DEADBEEF  CHEMICALS  321.0  19-11-2017  14288.0  UK  State  0.00%   3000   
1  DEADBEEF  CHEMICALS  321.0  19-11-2017  14288.0   0      0  5.00%  10750   

   Integ  
0    0.0  
1  537.5
```